# Changing focus to next right widget in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have a few EditText that are dynamically generated. I want to change the focus to the next EditText once the required length is reached. i have put all the Edit Texts on an ArrayList and am trying to add an event to shift the focus to next one but nothing seems to be working.
i cannot call the editText field by id because they are dynamically generated.

```
    final ArrayList<EditText> myEt = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    for(int a = 0; a < g2.getChildCount(); a++){//g2 is parent layout

        if(g2.getChildAt(a) instanceof EditText);
        myEt.add((EditText) g2.getChildAt(a));

    }

    for(int b =0; b>myEt.size()-1; ++b){
         final EditText e;
         final EditText e1;
        e = (EditText) myEt.get(b);
        e1 = (EditText) myEt.get(b+1);
        e.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if(e.getText().toString().length() > 4){
                    e.clearFocus();
                    e1.requestFocus();
                }


                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "once the required length is reached"?

Comment: once the user enter 4 words then it should shift to the one to the right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442622/how-to-change-the-focus-to-next-edit-text-in-android

Comment: cant call the Edit text like that as they are generated automatically. I don't know their id's

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       if(s.length()==Your required length)
           {
               input2.requestFocus();
           }

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            if(s.length()==Your required length)
           {
               input2.requestFocus();
           }
        }
    });
```