# How to move to previous edittext on pressing back in android using addtextchangelistener

Tags: android, kotlin

[I want to move back from second edit text to first after I press back and how can it be done using the addtextchangelisterner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNYHv.png)

Comment: You can override the `onBackPressed()` method, check if the text box is empty, if empty just call `super.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19442622/how-to-change-the-focus-to-next-edit-text-in-android)
This is an example:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

         edtPasscode1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(sb.length()==0&edtPasscode1.length()==1)
                 {
                     sb.append(s);
                     edtPasscode1.clearFocus();
                     edtPasscode2.requestFocus();
                     edtPasscode2.setCursorVisible(true);

                 }
             }

             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {

                 if(sb.length()==1)
                 {

                     sb.deleteCharAt(0);

                 }

             }

             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 if(sb.length()==0)
                 {

                     edtPasscode1.requestFocus();
                 }

             }
         });
```